# PHP Email Form

Tags: php, html

Could anyone tell me if there is something wrong with the code or a better way to modify it? for some reason when i hit submit on my contact form it displays the "error.html" page but i still get an email sent to my account.

```
$EmailTo = "example@example.com";
$Subject = "Contact Submission";

$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Budget = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['budget'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

// prepare email body text
$Body = 'Contact Submission'."\n";
$Body .= 'Name:        '   .$Name."\n";
$Body .= 'Email:       '   .$Email."\n";
$Body .= 'Budget:      '   .$Budget."\n";
$Body .= 'Message:     '   .$Message."\n";


// send email 
$success_email = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");

// redirect to success page
// CHANGE THE URL BELOW TO YOUR "THANK YOU" PAGE
    if ($success){
     header ('location:thankyou.html');
    } 
    else{
    header ('location:error.html');
    }
```

Comment: it's good form to put an exit; under your location headers - to ensure the page won't be parsed in an unlikely event

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
if ($success){
```

to

```
if ($success_email){
```

**$success** doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  $EmailTo = "example@example.com";
> $Subject = "Contact Submission";
>
> $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
> $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
> $Budget = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['budget'])); 
> $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
>
> // prepare email body text
> $Body = 'Contact Submission'."\n";
> $Body .= 'Name:            '   .$Name."\n";
> $Body .= 'Email:           '   .$Email."\n";
> $Body .= 'Budget:          '   .$Budget."\n";
> $Body .= 'Message:     '   .$Message."\n";
>
>
> // send email 
> $success_email = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");
>
> // redirect to success page
> // CHANGE THE URL BELOW TO YOUR "THANK YOU" PAGE
>     if ($success_email){
>      header ('location:thankyou.html');
>     } 
>     else{
>     header ('location:error.html');
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Checking for empty for redirecting error page
if(empty($Name) || empty($Email)||empty($Budget)) 
{
    header('Location:error.html');
    exit;
}

//Send the email! if the fileds are not empty
mail($EmailTo, $Subject,$Body,"From: <$Email>");

//One the email is sent, Redirect to thankyou page.
header('Location: thankyou.html');
```